Как поправить ошибку undefined в FormGroup в Angular?
Помогите разобраться с ошибкой undefined в FormGroup, есть следующий фрагмент HTML кода
<mat-tab i18n-lable lable="Некие параметры" [formGroup]="controlFormModel.form"> 
// ...      
</mat-tab>

и код .ts в котром инциализируется свойство form
export class SettingsComponent {
 controlFormModel: ControlFormModel;
}

async ngOnInit() {
 this.controlFormModel= new ControlFormModel();
}

export class ControlFormModel{
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this._createForm();
    });

  private _createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      deviceNumber: 0,
      identifierType: IdentifierType.controlPoint
    });
}

Но при загрузке страницы, в консоли падает ошибка ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'form'), подскажите, как можно поправить?

Возможно экземпляра ControlFormModel не существует, из-за этой ошибки }) в конструкторе.

@AlexanderLonberg, поправил, но ошибка осталась

А зачем ngOnInit  сделан как async, возможно что из-за этого проблемы. Как вариант, можно перенести инициализацию из ngOnInit в конструктор или при инициализации поля
